# Why do my images not stay where they are?

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have a small but annoying issue here. My footer and background image stay with the page when on different resolutions or zoomed in and out (because of the footer being fixed and the background image being positioned in the center) but my other images don't seem to stay with the page, they move on their own given a change in different resolutions or if I zoom in and out. Here's my code/screenshots of what's happening:

Screenshots:

My view of the webpage (1920x1080): http://gyazo.com/11c8a55c697696eb7667fdf23f903bb9

Here is my code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JobwRB

Try scroll zooming in codepen and I'll think you'll see what I mean. Is media queries worth a read here? Or will have to to put everything into a container?

Thanks for any help received.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="body.css" type="text/css"/>
     </head>
         <body>
            <div>
               <a href="#" id="javaPic" title="Java"></a>
               <a href="#" id="htmlcssPic" title="HTML/CSS"></a>
               <a href="#" id="javascriptPic" title="JavaScript"></a>
               <a href="#" id="phpPic" title="PHP"></a>
            </div>

        <div id="img">
              <img src="images/deets.png">
        </div>

<div id="footer">
    <ul id="footer_menu">
         <li class="homeButton"><a href="index.html"></a></li>

        <li><a href="page2.html">Profile</a>
            <div class="three_column_layout">
                <div class="col_3">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="page2.html">Work Exp</a>
            <div class="two_column_layout">
                    </div>
        </li>

              <li><a href="page2.html">Qualifications</a>
                    <div class="two_column_layout">
                          <div class="col_2">
                                     <a class="headerLinks">Test</a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="notifications">

            <li>
                          <a href="#" class="notificationIcons"><img src="images/twitter.png"</a>
                    </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="notificationIcons"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Footer CSS:

```
body{
  background:rgba(20,20,20,1);
}
#footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 font-family:Arial;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
 border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 
 inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#footer h2{
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:#CC0000; 
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 margin-left:10px;  
}
#footer p{
 color:white;
 font-size:12px;
 float:left;
 padding:0px 10px;
 margin:10px 0px; 
}
#footer img{
 border:none;
}
#footer li ul{
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px;
 margin-bottom:12px;
}
.clear{
 clear:both;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 visibility:hidden;
 width:0px;
 height:0px; 
}
#footer .whiteBorder{
 border:1px solid white;
}
#footer .img_left{
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
 width:40px;
}
#footer .black_box{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 padding:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 border-radius:5px; 
}
#footer #notifications{
 float:right;
 width:auto;
 margin:5px 15px 0px;
 padding:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#footer #notifications li{
 margin-right:12px;
 float:left;
 width:24px;
 padding:0px;
 height:32px;
 list-style:none;
}
#footer #notifications li:hover{
 margin-top:-1px;
}
#a .notificationIcons span{
 display:none;
 font-size:12px;
 color:white;
 bottom:45px;
 width:150px;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #333333;
 padding:5px;
 margin-left:-70px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
}
#a .notificationIcons:hover span{
 display:block; 
}
#footer_menu{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 width:auto;
}
#footer_menu li{
 list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 width:75px;
 float:left;
 font-size:12px;
 padding:12px 14px 14px 14px;
 border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#footer_menu li:hover{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#footer_menu li a{
 display:block;
 color:#CCCCCC;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#footer_menu li a:hover{
 color:white;
}
#footer_menu .homeButton{
 padding:5px 8px 0px 5px; 
 border:none;
 background:none; 
}
#footer_menu .homeButton a{
 background:url("C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/greyhouse1.png") top left no-repeat;
 width:36px;
 height:30px; 
}
#footer_menu .homeButton:hover{
 background:none;
}
#footer_menu .homeButton a:hover{
 background:url("C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/whitehouse2.png") top left no-repeat;
}

/*Programs menu drop-up box*/

#footer_menu li ul.dropup{
 display:none;
}
#footer_menu li:hover ul.dropup{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
 bottom:40px;
 border:1px solid #111111;
 border-bottom:none;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#foot_menu li:hover li{
 float:none;
 background:none;
 border:none;
 border-bottom:1px solid #111111;
 padding:12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

/*Drop up default links*/

#footer_menu li:hover a{
 color:#aaaaaa;
}
#footer_menu li:hover a:hover{
 color:white;
}

/*Header links*/

.headerLinks {
  display:none !important;
 }

#footer_menu li:hover a.headerLinks{
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:underline;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 color:#CC0000;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:10px;
 display:block !important;
}
#footer_menu li:hover a.headerLinks:hover{
 color:white;
 cursor:pointer;
}

/*List links*/

#footer_menu li:hover a.listLinks{
 font-size:12px;
 color:#aaaaaa;
 margin-left:10px;
}
#footer_menu li:hover a.listLinks:hover{
 color:white;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#footer_menu .right{
 float:right;
 right:0px;
 margin-right:2px;
 border-right:none;
 border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}

/*Layouts*/

#footer .one_column_layout,
#footer .two_column_layout,
#footer .three-column_layout,{
 margin:4px;
 position:absolute;
 padding-bottom:15px;
 display:none;
 text-align:left;
}

/*Width of each layout*/

#footer .one_column_layout{width:140px;}
#footer .two_column_layout{width:280px;}
#footer .three_column_layout{width:420px;}

/*Display Dropup menus on hover */

#footer_menu li:hover .one_column_layout,
#footer_menu li:hover .two_column_layout,
#footer_menu li:hover .three_column_layout{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:left; 
 margin:0 0 0 -15px;
 bottom:40px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#footer.col_1, 
#footer.col_2,
#footer.col_3{
display:block;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-right:5px;  
}
#footer.col_1{width:130px;}
#footer.col_2{width:270px;}
#footer.col_3{width:410px;}
```

Body CSS:

```
body { 
 background-image:url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/background1.png');
 box-shadow:5px 5px 2px;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-position:center;  
 max-width:1080px; 
}
#javaPic {
 width:366px;
 height:236px;
 display:block;
 border:1px solid white;
 background:transparent url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/java.png');
 position:fixed;
 top:5%;
 left:28.8%;
 max-width:100%;
}

#javaPic:hover {
 background-image: url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/java2.png');
}
#htmlcssPic {
 width:366px;
 height:236px;
 display:block;
 border:1px solid white;
 background:transparent url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/htmlcss.png');
 position:fixed;
 top:5%;
 right:28.8%;
 max-width:100%;
}

#htmlcssPic:hover {
  background-image: url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/htmlcss2.png');
}
#javascriptPic {
 width:366px;
 height:236px;
 display:block;
 border:1px solid white;
 background:transparent url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/javascript.png');
 position:fixed;
 top:35%;
 left:28.8%;
 max-width:100%;
}
#javascriptPic:hover {
 background-image: url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/javascript2.png');
}
#phpPic {
 width:366px;
 height:236px;
 display:block;
 border:1px solid white;
 background:transparent url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/php.png');
 position:fixed;
 top:35%;
 right:28.8%;
 max-width:100%;
}

#phpPic:hover {
 background-image: url('C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/CV Website/images/php2.png');
}
#img {
 position:fixed;
 top:0.5%;
 left:28.8%;
 display:block;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: u've called ur images from ur local path (c:\....), so we can't assist u without seeing any issues.. try to make a fiddle and proceed..

Comment: I've also added borders around where they would be, so in codepen you can follow the border (when scroll zooming or in a different resolution). The images do not stay fixed with the centre of the website but move off where they please.